# calculating propagation delay

Tags: delay, propagation

[image]

We assume that every gate's delay is (microsecond). what is total propagation delay?

Comment: Maximum or minimum?

Comment: if may  both please

Comment: My question should be regarded as a clue.

Comment: maximum...what's different?

Comment: @john What have you tried[?](https://i.imgur.com/aY1G9CM.png)

Comment: can you explain me how calculating?thanks

Comment: Harry Svensson....calculating total propagation delay.that's it

Comment: What is your guess....let us hear that first

Comment: This is similar to one of those puzzles we have played at school. Find the shortest path from school to the home. Here you have to find the longest.

Comment: you mean i should find longest path for every input?

Comment: yea. from each input find all possible paths to output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you insist on not trying[.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItlPu.png) Then here's a major hint.

Look at the **A** input.

- It enters an AND gate (1 µs)
- The output of that AND gate enters an OR gate (2 µs)
- The output of that OR gate enters an AND gate (3 µs)
- The output of that AND gate enters an OR gate (4 µs)
- The output of that OR gate enters a triple OR gate (5 µs)

So that path that I randomly took, took 5 µs.

Now do what I did for all paths. The answer is the path that resulted in the longest time.

Here's another hint, the longest path begins at **B** or **C**.

Comment: All the hints were buried beneath the explicit in there. :-)